# Can't get instafeed to work at all

Tags: javascript, html, css, instafeedjs

For whatever reason, Instafeed (http://instafeedjs.com/) isn't displaying anything. I'm using localhost if that makes a difference.

My markup is as follows:

```
<div class="photo-container">
<div id="instafeed"></div>
</div>
```

I've set the height of photo-container in the CSS.

Here is my JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var userFeed = new Instafeed({
          clientId: '33a######################76569e',
          get: 'user',
          userId: 22####892,
          accessToken: '2######92.46######.108#######403e8088#####05',
          limit: 9,
          useHttp: true,
          target: 'instafeed',
          template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" /><div class="likes">&hearts; {{likes}}</div></a>'
          });
          userFeed.run();
    </script>
```

I also have the following line above the script:

```
<script src="js/instafeed.min.js"></script>
```

I can't seem to find the issue here? The strange thing is that it works in JSFiddle but not on localhost. It just has an empty space is where the photo-container is. I've also uploaded it online and it doesn't work there either.

Comment: The common question here: Are you sure that `js/instafeed.js` is accessible from your html page?

Comment: Almost definitely http://i.imgur.com/p7t3qlo.png

Comment: Check your JS files in Network via Developer Tools. If your all JS is ok, please update here.

Comment: Ah it was coming up with a 403 forbidden error in Network. I've changed the permissions (chmod 777) but that doesn't seem to fix my issue although the status is back to normal.

Comment: Any advice @Karmacoma ?

Comment: Please put your code in this JSFiddle and alert here. http://jsfiddle.net/Rochefort/t84s7gpx/